# How do I formulate ExcludePath regex for Python DeepDiff in this JSON?

Tags: python

I want to exclude Key7 and Key8 from the [DeepDiff](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff) comparison. Even if the values of key7 and key 8 are different, I don't want DeepDiff to consider it.

```
diff = DeepDiff(object1, object2, excludePath)
```

The sample object looks like below:

Obj1:

```
{
    "KEY1": "VALUE1",
    "KEY2": "VALUE2",
    "KEY3": "VALUE3",
    "KEY4": 4,
    "KEY5": [
        {
            "KEY6": "VALUE",
            "KEY7": 6,
            "KEY8": VALUE
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you could add example `obj1`,`obj2` so we could run it ant test some ideas.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: `excludePath=("root['KEY5']['KEY7']","root['KEY5']['KEY8']")`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exclude_regex_paths` and pass a regex or a set or list of path regexes to exclude.
In your case:

```py
>>> DeepDiff(object1, object2, exclude_regex_paths=r"\['KEY[78]'\]")
```

More details on `exclude-regex-paths` in the [documentation](https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/current/exclude_paths.html#exclude-regex-paths)